# How can I give variables to the event handler?

Tags: wxpython

How can I give a variable to a function when I bind something? As a simple example:

```
def test(self):
    self.MyTextCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.something, AnyVariable)

def something(self, event, x)
    # do something
    print x
```

As you see, I want to give the value "AnyVariable" to the function "something" so that it will be used as the "x". How can I do this? This example doesn't work.

Edit:
@  Paul McNett:
Yeah, what I'm trying to do is more like:

```
def test(self):
    self.MyTextCtrl1.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.something, Variable1)
    self.MyTextCtrl2.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.something, Variable2)
    self.MyTextCtrl3.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.something, Variable3)

def something(self, event, x)
    # do something by including x
```

x=Variable1 when "MyTextCtrl1" is edited, x=Variable2 when "MyTextCtrl2" is edited and x=Variable3 when "MyTextCtrl3" is edited.

Of course I also could write 3 different functions ("def something1", "def something2", "def something3") and bind them to "MyTextCtrl1", "MyTextCtrl2" or "MyTextCtrl3". But I thought it could be much easier when I use this variable instead ;)

Comment: It's not really a variable if it is going to be the same value whenever the event is raised, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the following approaches should do it:

- Introduce a global variable (variable declaration outside the function scope at module level).

  ```
  x = None
  def test(self):
      self.MyTextCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.something)

  def something(self, event):
      global x
      x = ... # alter variable on event
  ```
- Introduce a member variable of a class.
- Furthermore [`wx.EVTHandler`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.EvtHandler-class.html#Bind) suggests anything as event handler that is callable. For this case I've written a simple class to hold one value (extendable for multiple values) and that implements a `__call__` method. Interfering special methods is an advanced topic, for this case I've put together example code:

  ```
  import wx

  class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, *args, **kwargs)
          sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
          self.SetSizer(sizer)
          b = wx.Button(self, -1, "Test")
          sizer.Add(b)
          b.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, TestHandler("foo"))
          self.Show()

  class TestHandler:
      def __init__(self, value):
          self.value = value

      def __call__(self, event):
          print event
          print "My value is:", self.value

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      app = wx.App()
      TestFrame("")
      app.MainLoop()
  ```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! If you have a look at my edit, I think your suggestion nr. 1 won't work for me. But I will try it with nr. 3 ;)